# how to maintain heights when floating and background hovers with fluid design

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout, jquery-hover

I have a couple of issues with my responsive layout.

1) the are height discrepancies on my boxes when changing the width of screen. Can this be fixed using heights?

2) I created a hover state using Jquery that gives the image a darker bg. The problem accurs when you adjust the screen size. Is it possible for the hover state to fit the image whatever the dimension of the container??

Please refer to images and fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/rJTmb/

```
    /*  CHART IT BTN ON POTS
    ===================================================================*/
    $(".display-box").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".charthis-btn").show();
        $(this).find(".hover-mask").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".charthis-btn").hide();
        $(this).find(".hover-mask").fadeOut();
    })
@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
    #upload-container ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: -100%;
        width: 42.08%;
    }
    #upload-container ul li span {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
        margin-left: 51.93%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #upload-container ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: -100%;
        width: 27.73%;
    }
    #upload-container ul li span {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+1) {
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: 34.29%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 68.59%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #upload-container ul li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: -100%;
        width: 20.8%;
    }
    #upload-container ul li span {
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+1) {
        margin-left: 0%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+2) {
        margin-left: 25.96%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+3) {
        margin-left: 51.93%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
    #upload-container ul li:nth-child(4n+4) {
        margin-left: 77.89%;
        margin-bottom: 3.85%;
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

Much appreciated!!! 
[image: There is a height difference on responsive -needs to be fixed]
[image: Hover states are out of line when screen changes]

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will help you, when you use clearfix, all heights are displayed correctly.

[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Cheers